# I'm getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error when trying to add an Node to the end of a Linked List in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So I've created a new Linked list and I'm having trouble inserting a new Node at the end of the Linked List. I've tried different iterations of traversing through the list but I think the problem is at the end where I'm trying to insert the node.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//Make a basic linked list and understand how it works -- displaying -- insert at end 

class Node {
public: 
    string m_name;
    Node *m_next;
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node *m_head;
    int m_size;
    LinkedList() { //constructor
        m_head = nullptr;
        m_size = 0;
    }
    void InsertAtEnd(Node *ptr) { //we must traverse to the end
        Node *temp = m_head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->m_next;
        }
        temp->m_next = ptr->m_next;
    }
    void Display() {
        Node *temp = m_head;
        if (temp == nullptr) {
            cout << "The linked list is empty!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            while (temp->m_next != nullptr) {
                cout << temp->m_name << " ";
                temp = temp->m_next;
            }
        }
    }

};

int main() {
    //creates the pointers
    Node *first = nullptr;
    Node *second = nullptr;

    //create nodes using pointers
    first = new Node();
    second = new Node();

    //add names to nodes
    first->m_name = "Mike";
    second->m_name = "Ethan";

    //insert these pointers into a newly constructed linked list
    LinkedList MyList;
    MyList.InsertAtEnd(first);
    MyList.InsertAtEnd(second);
    MyList.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what value `temp` has after `while (temp != nullptr) {` And what will then happen in `temp->m_next = ptr->m_next;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a debugger to step through your code. In your function

```
 void InsertAtEnd(Node *ptr) { //we must traverse to the end
        Node *temp = m_head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->m_next;
        }
        temp->m_next = ptr->m_next; // but temp is nullptr. BOOM
    }
```

you are iterating till `temp` is `nullptr`. But at that point, doing `temp->m_next` is UB. You need to stop just before that. Also, you should link up `ptr`, not `ptr->m_next`

```
 void InsertAtEnd(Node *ptr) { //we must traverse to the end
        Node *temp = m_head;
        while (temp->m_next != nullptr) { // look ahead
            temp = temp->m_next;
        }
        temp->m_next = ptr;  // just ptr
    }
```

Of course, you also have to do an additional check in case the linked list is empty

```
 void InsertAtEnd(Node *ptr) { //we must traverse to the end
    if (m_head == nullptr)
         m_head = ptr;
    else {    
    Node *temp = m_head;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->m_next;
        }
        temp->m_next = ptr->m_next;
    }
}
```

You appear to be doing the opposite thing in your Display function. There you should iterate until `temp` is `nullptr`. Otherwise you won't print the last element.

Also, please don't do `using namespace std;`